# Make the entire symfony app read-only

Tags: doctrine, symfony

I need to set up a live demo of a Symfony app.

How can I make everything read-only? The users should be able to try all the features but not make any persistent change visible to others.

I could remove the INSERT and UPDATE privileges to the mysql user, but that would be an ugly error 500 when they try to save something...

Comment: don't persist on database but leverage html5 client side storage with localstorage for example ? https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: I can't rewrite the app I'll only have a few hours tonight to work on it :) and it must be ready for tomorrow

Comment: Ok... So what about storing all data based on user ? You'll have common data user-free and personalized data if the logged user make some change. It's only for demo purpose, right ? Anyway, good luck :)

Comment: This really the sort of thing you need to design in from the start.  In your case, let them make the changes and just periodically restore the database.

Comment: Easy way to make it with event listener => to check role of any flush http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

Comment: maybe create a cron that removes the data from datadase (including the user changes) , and recreate it with your predefined data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick and dirty way to make your entire app Read-Only.

**AppBundle/EventSubscriber/EntitySubscriber.php**

```
namespace AppBundle\EventSubscriber;

use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreFlushEventArgs;


class EntitySubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{    
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'preFlush'
        ];
    }

    public function preFlush(PreFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();
        $entityManager->clear();
    }
}
```

**services.yml**

```
app.entity_subscriber:
    class: AppBundle\EventSubscriber\EntitySubscriber
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you've already made it. But if not:

1. Use dummy database. Copy it from original DB. Let them play. Drop it when you don't need it.
2. If you have no access to database creation and drop you can still do the trick. Just add temporary prefixes to table names in Doctrine entities. No need to rewrite the entire app, just a few lines. Run migrations to create new tables. Drop them whenever you want later.
3. Use virtual machine. Make a snapshot before the show. Roll back to the saved snapshot after the show.

These are more or less easy ways and they are platform independent.

Changing this based on the Symfony app level might have one of two disadvantages. You either do not save anything and thus your demo is not working so nice to show it to the customer. Or you have to do to much manipulations with the code and throw this huge work away right after the show.

Comment: you're on to something here.. Configure Doctrine to use memory as it's storage vs. actually storing data on disk.  Reboot the instance and the 'db' is reset to it's original state.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [Session](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html) to do that or Memcache that you can implement in Symfony (Some examples are available on the web). Hope this will help.